# How do you drop a column in firebird

Tags: sql, firebird

I'm using firebird and attempting to drop a column but the following SQL does not work:

```
ALTER TABLE student DROP COLUMN id;
```

Comment: Take a look at the [reference manuals](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/reference-manuals/) for Firebird. Specifically for this look at the Interbase 6 Language Reference + the Firebird 2.5 Language Reference Update

Answer (score 9):

You must omit the "COLUMN" keyword:

```
ALTER TABLE student DROP id;
```

Answer (score 4):

**Try this**

```
ALTER TABLE Table_name DROP columnname;
```

[refer this link](http://www.dtsql.com/db/db_firebird.htm)